# initialize a array of UIimages

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization, uiimage

My swift code below is trying to initizilie a array of UIimages. Right now the code is causing a compile error. I have also added a photo of where my images are store in Xcode. The code is below. 
[image]

```
let image1 = UIImage(named: "a.png")
let image2 = UIImage(named: "b.png")
let image3 = UIImage(named: "c.png")
let image4 = UIImage(named: "d.png")
let image5 = UIImage(named: "e.png")
let image6 = UIImage(named: "f.png")
lazy var images: [UIImage?] = { [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6] }()
```

Comment: Why didn't you add the images in `Assets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the bellow code

```
let images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
```

when you are creating new empty array, then only the type need to mentioned and the open close parenthesis is also required

To declare empty array of images

```
let images = [UIImage]()
```

Your code can also rewrite like bellow, instead of creating these much variables unnecessarily

```
let images: [UIImage?] = [
    UIImage(named: "a.png"),
    UIImage(named: "b.png"),
    UIImage(named: "c.png"),
    UIImage(named: "d.png"),
    UIImage(named: "e.png"),
    UIImage(named: "f.png")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the following line to create an image array

```
let images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly bracket and parentheses.

```
lazy var images: [UIImage?] =  [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]
```